# How can I draw things just in an area that can have a shape such as the shape of the letter B and not draw outside this form?

Tags: libgdx

I want to draw stuff on an image, for Example, if I have a letter, as an image and I want to draw on the letter it is necessary that this image is touchable.
This is what I did:

```
Image.addListener (new clickListener () {
public boolean Touchdown (InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button)
{
/ * posCurseurX = x;
posCurseurY = y * /


// Begin to draw on the screen


touch = true;
traitSprite = new Sprite (rectangleTexture, 0.0, tailleTrait, tailleTrait)

traitSprite.setPosition (x-tailleTrait / 2 (height) -y - tailleTrait / 2);
tabRectangelSprite.add (traitSprite);
counter ++;

dessinerTrait (touch);
dessinerCurseur ();
// The index of the number of meter rectangle forming a line

return true;
}
});
```

But I want to add another listener for mouse movements, but it does not work with MouseMove.
and the other thing I would like, is to draw that if I'm on my image. If the cursor position is not between the coordinates of the image so I will not draw.

that's what I tried:

```
if (posCurseurX> = image.getX posCurseurX && <= + image.getX image.getWidth) {
```

..}

But the texture does not necessarily have that width, that's an example:
[image]

Comment: To clarify, do you want the user to only be able to draw on the green area of the B, or allow them to draw anywhere on the B image including the white spaces?

Comment: no I just want it to be able to draw in the green zone, and thank you for the reply,do you have any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Check out the principles behind [stencil buffers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stencil_buffer) and/or masking.

Essentially what you want to do is generate a mask/stencil to mark out your drawing area and use this mask to decide if the user can draw or not.

For example, take your shapes you want the user to draw on and render them as pure white into a full-screen buffer, with a default colour of black. When the user tries to draw you simply take the screen pixel coordinate and lookup that pixel in the full-screen buffer. If the pixel is white, then the user can draw, if it's black the user can't.

You can avoid this check altogether. If you just want the user to be able to draw on top of an image, just let them draw everywhere, but use a stencil buffer to limit the area of the image you show on the screen - much like using a stencil.

In other words, let the user draw all over the screen but only show the parts of the image that are overlaid by the B shape.

How to do this? Draw B to a stencil buffer. Let the user draw all over a full screen buffer. Draw the buffer with the B stencil in place.

If you don't want to use stencil buffers there are a host of other methods such as custom shaders that do the query for white in the mask or using the black & white stencil buffer as the alpha channel of the buffer the user is drawing to.

Check out this example of [OpenGL stencil buffers](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenGL_Programming/Stencil_buffer). There are numerous examples of how to use this and they can be used on Android devices. [Here](https://github.com/mattdesl/lwjgl-basics/wiki/libgdx-masking) is one that seems to be related to doing this process in libgdx.

Comment: This is the first time I discovered this method,thank you very much.what is the best way in your opinion?

Comment: But the question is, how to cut the mask shape B?

Comment: Check out the tutorials linked in the answer and have a google-about. There are many ways to do this and you'll know best which is good for you. Usually generating the mask is done in the same way as rendering to the screen, but with some different flags/options set.